# RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged not work, list in the adapter is still empty after the notifyDataSetChanged method

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, notifydatasetchanged

notigyDataSetChanged not work! 
list in the adapter is still empty after the notifyDataSetChanged method.

MainActivity:

```
//left menu
mRvLeftMenu = (RecyclerView) mSlidingMenu.findViewById(R.id.rv_left_menu);
//set layout manager
mRvLeftMenu.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
//init list
mSlidingData = new ArrayList<>();
mLeftMenuAdapter = new LeftMenuAdapter(this, mSlidingData);
//set adapter
mRvLeftMenu.setAdapter(mLeftMenuAdapter);


@Override
public void onLoadFinished(int requestType, BaseResultBean resultBean) {
    switch (requestType) {
        case MyConstants.REQUEST_RESULT_NEWS_CENTER:
            List<NewsResultBean.DataBean> list = ((NewsResultBean) resultBean).getData();
```

works well like this

```
//                mLeftMenuAdapter = new LeftMenuAdapter(this, list);
//                mRvLeftMenu.setAdapter(mLeftMenuAdapter);
```

if I just add the data to the mSlidingData it didn't work, RecyclerView wouldn't refresh! why?

```
            mSlidingData.addAll(list);
            mLeftMenuAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

and after the notifyDataSetChanged call the mList in Adapter is still empty! Same as bellow.

```
            mRvLeftMenu.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
            break;
    }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class LeftMenuAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<LeftMenuAdapter.VH> {
    private List<NewsResultBean.DataBean> mList;
    private Context mContext;
    private OnItemClickListener mOnItemClickListener;

    public LeftMenuAdapter(Context context, List<NewsResultBean.DataBean> list) {
        mList = list;
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public VH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = View.inflate(mContext, R.layout.item_left_menu, null);
        return new VH(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final VH holder, int position) {
        holder.mTvLeftMenu.setText(mList.get(position).getTitle());
        final int tempPosition = position;
        holder.mView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mOnItemClickListener != null){
                    mOnItemClickListener.onItemClicked(v,tempPosition);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mList.size();
    }

    class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        @BindView(R.id.tv_left_menu)
        TextView mTvLeftMenu;
        View mView;
        public VH(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            mView = itemView;
            ButterKnife.bind(this,mView);
        }
    }

    interface OnItemClickListener{
        void onItemClicked(View view,int position);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener onItemClickListener) {
        mOnItemClickListener = onItemClickListener;
    }
}
```

Comment: You are passing the empty arraylist  `mSlidingData`  to the adapter contructor. Which is never changed. You need to add the items before callingvthe adapter class.

Comment: Are you changing mSlidingData value somewhere in your activity?

Comment: Yes, I checked my code again, I changed mSlidingData value after a network request.

Answer (score 0):

THX for your help fellows!
I made a stupid mistake, I changed mSlidingData to another list after a network request.

```
//after network request
private void processResult(String response) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    NewsResultBean newsResultBean = gson.fromJson(response, NewsResultBean
            .class);
    Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: " + newsResultBean.toString());
    //pass the result data to MainActivity,changed the mSlidingData to a new list,
    //cause RecyclerView notifyDataSetChanged method not work!
//                        mActivity.setSlidingData(newsResultBean.getData());
```

setSlidingData method like this:

```
public void setSlidingData(List<NewsResultBean.DataBean> slidingData) {
    mSlidingData = slidingData;
}
```